# Song in makefile?

Tags: makefile

I want my computer to play a song when my Makefile is completed, is this possible?

I searched on internet but I didn't find anything.

Comment: On which os do you want to do that?

Comment: Principaly on opensuse 12.3 or linux mint 16

Comment: As the last step in your Makefile rules, put in whatever command you would otherwise type from the command line to play a song. Whatever that command is, this is not the site to ask for help about it as it has nothing to do with programming; that you want to include it as a step in a programming-related tool is incidental.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should be more precise with questions, here. What do you don't know, "how to play a sound file" or "how to add a `makefile` rule" that achieves this.

Answer (score 3):

While the question of "Why?" is the first that springs to mind; the basic principle is the same as that of playing any song from the command line, or indeed executing any function in a Makefile.

First, install either [mpg123](http://www.mpg123.de/) or [mpg321](http://mpg321.sourceforge.net/); and then invoke it within the appropriate directives in your Makefile, like so:

```
# at the start of the file
MP3PLAYER = mpg123

# at the relevant spot for playing
$(MP3PLAYER) completed.mp3
```

It's worth noting that any other command line MP3 player will do, and depending on your system, you might also be able to tell your regular MP3 player to play the song instead.

On Mac OS X, this can be achieved through the use of osascript:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "iTunes" to play "completed.mp3"'
```

On most other *NIX systems, you can use the always handy VLC; simply set the `MP3PLAYER` variable to `vlc`; or `open -a VLC` for Mac OS X.